# Why all files of my npm package are installed in node_modules?

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-publish

Here is what I have in `node_modules` when I install my package:

[image]

Even though I am using this [`files` field](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#files) in package.json:

```
"files": [
    "./dist"
  ]
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you misunderstood what the `files` field does:

[The optional files field is an array of file patterns that describes the entries to be included when your package is installed as a dependency](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#files)

The `files` field is used to define files that should be imported alongside your library when another project install your project as a npm package.

Comment: Exactly. I created a package and now testing its locally as written on [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-scoped-public-packages#testing-your-package) and when i open my installed package inside node_modules it has all sourse files instead of heaving only **dist**, **license** and **readme** despite i have **files** field in package.json

Answer (score 0):

Thats how module works.if you don't like node_modules folder try [Yarn2](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install) .
Same thing.but different module folder name.

Answer (score -2):

Thats how npm works. All yours external dependencies will be downloaded to node_modules.

[https://medium.com/maxkimambo/how-does-node-module-loading-actually-work-8aa63849f5ae#:~:text=Modules%20are%20the%20building%20block,are%20using%20ES6%20Javascript%20code.&text=included%20in%20your%20app.,can%20have%20their%20own%20package](https://medium.com/maxkimambo/how-does-node-module-loading-actually-work-8aa63849f5ae#:%7E:text=Modules%20are%20the%20building%20block,are%20using%20ES6%20Javascript%20code.&text=included%20in%20your%20app.,can%20have%20their%20own%20package).